# Is there any alternative for ioctl() in linux to interact with nvme drives

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, systems-programming, nvme

I am working on a testing tool for nvme-cli(written in c and can run on linux).

For SSD validation purpose, we are actually looking for sending I/O commands to a particular Submission queue(IO Queue pair). We needed this because we wanted threading, but for threading to happen we need to send I/O requests to different queues else the I/O requests would be processed serially.

So is there any way in `ioctl()` where we can specify the Submission queue IDs?

OR

Is there other thing similar to `ioctl()` where we can specify the Submission queue IDs?

Since i am new to nvme or ioctl, please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try SPDK (https://github.com/spdk/spdk) which contains an user-space NVMe driver. It is written in C. Youc an find its NVMe driver APIs in spdk/include/spdk/nvme.h. For example, spdk_nvme_ctrlr_cmd_io_raw() is used to send any kinds of IO commands to the device, with any created qpair.

You can also try Pynvme (https://github.com/cranechu/pynvme), a python extension of SPDK. Its IOWorker just sends requests within separated process and qpair.