# Is there any way for ioctl() in linux to specify submission queue ID for a nvme IO request

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, systems-programming, nvme

I am working on a testing tool for nvme-cli(written in c and can run on linux).

For SSD validation purpose, we are actually looking for sending I/O commands to a particular Submission queue(IO Queue pair). We needed this because we wanted threading, but for threading to happen we need to send I/O requests to different queues else the I/O requests would be processed serially.

So is there any way in ioctl() where we can specify the Submission queue IDs?

Here is how a nvme IO is requested with `ioctl()`

```
 ioctl(fd, NVME_IOCTL_SUBMIT_IO, &io);
```

This invokes `nvme_ioctl()` in the driver [here](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.5/source/drivers/nvme/host/core.c#L1042)!

`nvme_ioctl()` intern invokes the `nvme_submit_io()` Function [here](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.5/source/drivers/nvme/host/core.c#L935)!

`nvme_submit_io()` has the a parameter `struct nvme_ns *ns` where the structure has a field name `queue`[view here](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.5/source/drivers/nvme/host/core.c#L980)!

I wanted to know if we can invoke `ioctl()` with a additional new parameter `queue_id` which is to be assigned to `queue` field of `struct nvme_ns *ns` in the `nvme_submit_io()` function.

Can I know if we can do like this?

If yes, please give me some brief steps.
If NO, please suggest me any possible solution.

Since i am new to nvme or ioctl, please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: This question is implied to be improved version of the [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47899389/is-there-any-alternative-for-ioctl-in-linux-to-interact-with-nvme-drives), isn't it? If so, instead of asking new question, **improve existing question** via editing. `I wanted to know if we can invoke ioctl() with a additional new parameter ...` - ioctl accepts exactly 3 parameters, you cannot pass more.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Can I end-up with any solution, is there any other way i can solve this?? Is the any other procedure alternative to `ioctl()` where we can send additional parameters??

Comment: Some of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47668183/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-ioctl-with-newcustomized-command) was about writting new ioctl command. Why do not follow that approach?

Comment: @Tsyvarev for adding new ioctl command, doesn't the device need to support that option?

Comment: Yes, device needs to be designed so. However, by this line `struct nvme_ns *ns = bdev->bd_disk->private_data;` (in `nvme_ioctl` function) I understand, that `ns` structure and its fields (with `.queue` among them) are *specific for the block device*. So, the only way to use another queue is to send ioctl request to **another file, representing another disk**. I am not familiar with nvme, but this is just the code means for me.

Comment: `@Tsyvarev`  regarding `writting new ioctl command` adding a new ioctl command requires addition of new modules(functions) in the driver. But from building a tool perspective, adding new modules for driver is not a good design. So we are interested in finding a way where we can use existing driver modules to get the required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Look a little bit into `nvme_submit_io()`, it calls `nvme_submit_user_cmd()`
[Refer here](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.5/source/drivers/nvme/host/core.c#L648). You will see `nvme_alloc_request(q, cmd, 0, NVME_QID_ANY)`. The request allocates to `NVME_QID_ANY` means it not specify QID and let the hardware queue mapping to decide which queue is going to send.

Back to your question. AFAIK, there has NO native way to specify QID when sending ioctl cmd. If you really want to. You need to modify native nvme source code and build your own nvme driver.

HINT: Try to let `nvme_alloc_request` can receive specified QID, instead of `NVME_QID_ANY`.